# Am I missing a limitation on double strike (for star wars lcg)?

Tags: star-wars-lcg

Example scenario (which I'm going to call "The Sam" since my 7 year son just beat me using a large subset of this):

Dark side has no defenders available, 3 undamaged 5 point objectives.  Light side's turn, light side of force is winning.

Light side objectives: Hit and Run, One of the 2 resource objectives, and the objective that gives you a -1 for first enhancement played.

Light side hand has yoda, light sabre, r2d2, binds all things, double strike, and target of opportunity as their 6 cards in their hand.

Light side does one point of damage during force struggle.

Deployment:
   Light side plays R2D2 (increases resources available to 6)
   Light side plays yoda (resource left: 3)
   Light side plays light sabre enhancment (rez left: 3)

Attack:
   Yoda attacks undamaged objective, plays TOO during unopposed edge battle, thereby doing 5 damage (TOO + light sabre + enhancement bonus + own strike + unopposed bonus)
   When focused to strike, light side plays double strike (rez left: 2)
   Light side then plays it binds all things (rez left: 1), picking up TOO + double strike
  Yoda repeats attack on 2nd undamaged objective and again uses double strike (rez left: 0), playing TOO again
  Yoda attacks 3rd objective, doing only 4 points of damage (no TOO), and actually could do an extra point of damage from hit and run.

Light side has just defeated 3 objectives and therefore wins.

Sub-questions: 
  Is there a rule limiting a single unit to only being able to attack 1 objective per turn that I'm not seeing?
  Is there some other limitation/rule exception that would prevent this?  (Beyond the whole dark side really should have at least one defender and this does require a non-trivial amount of luck to get this exact combination of cards)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsLCG/comments/5cqh5a/am_i_missing_a_limitation_on_double_strike/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The engagement isn't over until all ready units have been focused to strike.  Double Strike must be played "after a Character unit is focused to strike," which means it can only be played, and therefore can only remove a focus token, DURING the engagement, allowing multiple strikes at the *same* objective. If you can destroy an undefended objective in one strike, playing Double Strike does nothing for you- your second strike has nothing to hit.
See "Resolving a strike" on p 20 of the rules, and "Engagment resolution" (p 31).   CArdgamedb.com is the best place for Star Wars rules and discussion. Some real experts post over there.  Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule preventing a single unit from attacking multiple objectives, so long as they are able to attack in the first place. Keep your defenses up as dark side (or any side, really). :)